# Springboot not reading Application.yml file when I set spring.active.profile

Tags: spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, properties-file, spring-profiles

I have application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml. I have Database props in it. When I set the spring.active.profile to dev and When I am doing a maven clean install, it's throwing me datasource.url not found error. (It's just not reading the yml files.)
But when I create another application.yml file and put the same props, it's reading it and the maven clean install is a success.

How Should I make my application read props from respective env files? (I know how to set profiles in IntelliJ) Below is my POM.

**I cannot put an include tag in POM because I want to read yml files according to profiles.**

See the image to get an idea of what I am trying to do. You can see the maven tool as well that I am using.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZZXw.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.askvedicastrologers</groupId>
    <artifactId>ask-vedic-astrologers</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>AskVedicAstrologers</name>
    <description>AskVedicAstrologers project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
<!--    <packaging>jar</packaging>-->
<!--    <modules>-->
<!--        <module>../search-engine</module>-->
<!--        <module>../post-engine</module>-->
<!--    </modules>-->
    <dependencies>
<!--        &lt;!&ndash;  Search-Engine module dependency  &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.askvedicastrologers</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>search-engine</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

<!--        &lt;!&ndash;  Post-Engine module dependency  &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.askvedicastrologers</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>post-engine</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-gateway -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--       Spring Security         -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I read that you have application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml files. Are they placed in src/main/resources?

Comment: Yes, is it placed inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `spring.profiles.active=dev` instead.

Comment: No, I want to use dev for the dev env file, and prod for the prod file. File names are like this: application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml and I don't have a test file as well. I am setting profile as dev in Intellij.

Comment: That was just a sample you can use dev or prod. Updated the answer for dev. Also notice the difference in yours and my syntax.

Comment: Tried it, not working.

Comment: Tried -Dspring.profiles.active=dev as VM options in IntelliJ. Not working.

Comment: -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev try this

Comment: No luck sir.  ;(  Stuck with it for 4 hours. Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Question updated, Please see image.

Comment: Can you please vote on my question? That would help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you have application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml, then you need to have one more application.yml. And on this application.yml file, you need to add

```
spring:
      active:
        profile: dev
```

For prod, config adds prod.

[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiB6Y.png)

I think this should solve your issue!

Comment: This did not work.  FYI, I can run the application in the dev and prod profile, but the only thing is maven clean and the maven install is not happening.

Comment: Question updated, Please see image.

Comment: I have a config for Gragle, can you  take a reference

if (project.hasProperty('prod')) {
    apply from: 'gradle/profile_prod.gradle'
} else {
    apply from: 'gradle/profile_dev.gradle'
}

in build.gradle and above file is define in gradle packages

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this a new bug introduced in new versions. I use to be able to debug and it will pickup the environment variables from the yaml file. Have tried different things like renaming file extention from yml to yaml, clearing cache and rebuild project, setting the active profile, removing the other profiles so there is only one active. None of them work.

As a work-around for the time-being since I really need to debug, I end up setting all the environment variables under `Edit Configuration > Environment Variables`. I am using `IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)`